# If $\mathbb{P}_{x}(\tau_y < \infty) = 1$ where $x \neq y$, does this imply a graph G is recurrent?

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains, random-walk

In the above, $x, y\in V$ (not necessarily for all points in the vertex set) and $\tau_y$ is the first hitting time of $y$ for a simple random walk on the vertex set $V$.

My gut feeling is that it is not true because we may not have symmetry in the graph but I cannot think of a simple example.

I thought maybe adding the point $ x = (1/2, 1/2, 1/2)$ to the graph of $\mathbb{Z}^3$ by an edge from $y = (0,0, 0)$ and then due to the transience of $\mathbb{Z}^3$ we have the transience of the new graph even though $\mathbb{P}_{x}(\tau_y < \infty) = 1$.

Comment: is the condition $\mathbb{P}_{x}(\tau_y < \infty) = 1$ true for all $x,y\in G$? or for some specific $x$?

Comment: just two specific points.

Comment: Recurrent means you need to get from $x$ to $y$ in G, and back again from $y$ to $x$. So unless you can get back to x with probability 1 (after starting from x and then going to y), you don't have recurrence, as you suspected.

Comment: Do you have a simple counter example?